# Создание таблицы Xamarin

Tags: c#, mysql, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Хочу перенести приложение windows forms c# на андроид и для этого решил использовать Xamarin.В windows forms для вывода данных из БД я использовал datagridview .Хотел узнать есть ли у Xamarin что то похожее. что бы вывести таблицу .
Вот как выглядит сама таблица

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: К сожалению, нет. Как такового элемента не существует. Насколько помню, есть Grid, но у него нет, как у dgv в winform, привязки данных (bindingsource). Но вы можете создать свой элемент. В интернете есть достаточно много решений проблемы

Comment: Нашел на гитхабе https://github.com/akgulebubekir/Xamarin.Forms.DataGrid вот такое решение. Про качество и работоспособность ничего сказать не могу - не тестировал, но можете попробовать взять за основу и доработать под свои нужды

Comment: Мобильник - не комп, комп - не мобильник. То, с чем удобно работать имея мышь и 101 клавишу, может оказаться совсем полным извратом на миниатюрном девайсе с тачскрином и экранной клавой. Продумывайте интерфейс заново.